# Is it possible to convert PICkit 3 programming connector to USB male A type

Tags: microchip, usbserial

I need to convert PICKit3's 6 pin connector to usb male. It is possible to convert rj11 to pickit and rj11 to usb male so i think its possible but i need to know what pin matches with which usb pin

Answer (score 0):

What on eart are you trying to do?  The protocol to program devices is not compatible with USB and it does not even use the same number of pins.

I suspect what you are trying to achieve is not possible and makes no sense . Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You want actual USB interface for programming or just thinking to have USB connector to easy plug in and out?
PICKit3 is not using USB protocol so you can't use USB to program your MCU. You better find out USB bootloader in case you really want to program your MCU via USB only.